# data.table non-equi join with min/max of joined value

Tags: r, data.table, non-equi-join

I'm trying to do a non-equi join in `data.table` and extract the min/max of the joined values in that join.

```r
set.seed(42)
dtA <- data.table(id=rep(c("A","B"),each=3), start=rep(1:3, times=2), end=rep(2:4, times=2))
dtB <- data.table(id=rep(c("A","B"),times=20), time=sort(runif(40, 1, 4)))
```

I'd like to preserve the min/max values of `time` when it is between `start` and `end` (and on `id`). Nominally this is just a non-equi join, but I can't find a combination of `by=.EACHI` or `mult="..."` that gets me what I want. Instead, the min/max typically are not aligned with the range I need. Unfortunately `roll=` does not support non-equi ranges.

```r
dtA[dtB, c("Min", "Max") := .(min(time), max(time)),
    on = .(id, start <= time, end > time), mult = "first"]
#        id start   end      Min      Max
#    <char> <int> <int>    <num>    <num>
# 1:      A     1     2 1.011845 3.966675
# 2:      A     2     3 1.011845 3.966675
# 3:      A     3     4 1.011845 3.966675
# 4:      B     1     2 1.011845 3.966675
# 5:      B     2     3 1.011845 3.966675
# 6:      B     3     4 1.011845 3.966675
dtA[dtB, c("Min", "Max") := .(min(time), max(time)),
    on = .(id, start <= time, end > time), by = .EACHI]
#        id start   end      Min      Max
#    <char> <int> <int>    <num>    <num>
# 1:      A     1     2 1.858419 1.858419
# 2:      A     2     3 2.970977 2.970977
# 3:      A     3     4 3.934679 3.934679
# 4:      B     1     2 1.766286 1.766286
# 5:      B     2     3 2.925237 2.925237
# 6:      B     3     4 3.966675 3.966675
```

The second is the closest ("Max" is correct), but what I'd like to be able to get is:

```r
       id start   end      Min      Max
   <char> <num> <int>    <num>    <num>
1:      A     1     2 1.011845 1.858419
2:      A     2     3 2.170610 2.970977
3:      A     3     4 3.115194 3.934679
4:      B     1     2 1.022002 1.766286
5:      B     2     3 2.164325 2.925237
6:      B     3     4 3.055509 3.966675
```

The real problem has around 400K or so rows with ranges joining in 2Mi rows of values, so I'd prefer to not do a full expansion of both frames to manually cut it back down to the size of `dtA`.

(I'm open to `collapse` suggestions.)

Comment: Does it have to be all in one line, or can I suggest doing it in two sweeps - `dtA[dtB[order(id,-time)], on = .(id, start <= time, end > time), min := time];dtA[dtB[order(id,time)], on = .(id, start <= time, end > time), max := time]` ?

Comment: The `tidyverse` equivalent `left_join(as.data.frame(dtA), as.data.frame(dtB), by=join_by(id, start < time, end > time)) %>% summarize(Min = min(time), Max = max(time), .by=c(id, start, end))`. Definitely slower because no threading, but also quite efficient.

Comment: Thanks Andre. While simple, this does what I'm trying to not do: a full expansion. I also don't have dplyr-1.1.0 yet for other reasons, but I appreciate your suggestion!

Comment: Are the by-group intervals in your real data mutually exclusive as in the example?

Comment: @jblood94 in the real data, `start` and `end` for each `id` abut, meaning `start == shift(end)`. It's time-ranges (`POSIXt`) in `dtA` and observations in `dtB`, and I need to find various stats (min, max, first, last, etc) of a dozen or so numeric columns. The end-result is going into a user-interactive app, so I want to get the runtime down as low as I can; part of that is reduction of the data going in, but the rest is just raw computation. (To make it worse, some of the fields are lat/lon, requiring either UTM-conversion and back, or `geosphere`-math, not cheap.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch the join around so it's `B[A]`, and then assign inside `A`:

```
dtA[,
    c("min","max") := dtB[
        dtA,
        on=.(id, time >= start, time < end), 
        .(min=min(x.time), max=max(x.time)),
        by=.EACHI][, c("min","max")]
    ]
dtA

#       id start   end      min      max
#   <char> <int> <int>    <num>    <num>
#1:      A     1     2 1.011845 1.858419
#2:      A     2     3 2.170610 2.970977
#3:      A     3     4 3.115194 3.934679
#4:      B     1     2 1.022002 1.766286
#5:      B     2     3 2.164325 2.925237
#6:      B     3     4 3.055509 3.966675
```

You can see it needs to be spun around, or otherwise the `.EACHI` group ends up being for each individual row in `B` instead of the matching rows in `B` inside the criteria for `A`:

```
dtB[dtA, on=.(id, time >= start, time < end), .N, by=.EACHI]
#       id  time  time     N
#   <char> <int> <int> <int>
#1:      A     1     2     5
#2:      A     2     3     6
#3:      A     3     4     9
#4:      B     1     2     4
#5:      B     2     3     6
#6:      B     3     4    10

dtA[dtB, on=.(id, start <= time, end > time), .N, by=.EACHI][, .(freq=.N), by=N]
#       N  freq
#   <int> <int>
#1:     1    40
```

This makes sense in the context of the `help("data.table::special-symbols")` description:

> Its usage is 'by=.EACHI' (or 'keyby=.EACHI') which invokes
> *grouping-by-each-row-of-i*

In the `DT[i, j, by]` logic, `dtA` then needs to contribute the rows for the grouping.

Comment: Looking, will check back later. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Update based on comments

Joins can be avoided altogether by using `nafill` after row-binding `dtA` to `dtB` and sorting. The solution below runs potentially orders of magnitude faster than a `.EACHI` non-equi join at the cost of considerably increased code complexity.

Unlike the previous answer, this makes **no assumption** about overlapping/non-overlapping intervals.

```
i <- 1:nrow(dtA)
dtA[
    , c("Min", "Max") := setorder(
      rbindlist(
        list( # list order is important
          dtA[, .(id, time = end, rw = .I, isStart = -1L)],
          dtA[, .(id, time = start, rw = .I, isStart = 1L)],
          dtB[, `:=`(rw = NA_integer_, isStart = 0L)]
        )
      ), id, time
    )[ # set the time at start/end points to NA
      !is.na(rw), time := NA_real_
    ][ # fill forward to get the max in each interval
      isStart <= 0L, time := nafill(time, "locf")
    ][ # fill backward to get the min in each interval
      isStart >= 0L, time := nafill(time, "nocb")
      # get the max and min, ordered by dtA row
    ][!is.na(rw), setorder(.SD, -isStart, rw)[, .(time[i], time[-i])]]
  # remove the no matches
  ][Min >= end | Min < start, c("Min", "Max") := NA_real_]

dtA
#>    id start end      Min      Max
#> 1:  A     1   2 1.011845 1.858419
#> 2:  A     2   3 2.170610 2.970977
#> 3:  A     3   4 3.115194 3.934679
#> 4:  B     1   2 1.022002 1.766286
#> 5:  B     2   3 2.164325 2.925237
#> 6:  B     3   4 3.055509 3.966675
```

As a function, along with a function for the `.EACHI` approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75738980/9463489):

```
fsort <- function(dtA, dtB) {
  i <- 1:nrow(dtA)
  dtA[
    , c("Min", "Max") := setorder(
      rbindlist(
        list(
          dtA[, .(id, time = end, rw = .I, isStart = -1L)],
          dtA[, .(id, time = start, rw = .I, isStart = 1L)],
          dtB[, `:=`(rw = NA_integer_, isStart = 0L)]
        )
      ), id, time
    )[
      !is.na(rw), time := NA_real_
    ][
      isStart <= 0L, time := nafill(time, "locf")
    ][
      isStart >= 0L, time := nafill(time, "nocb")
    ][!is.na(rw), setorder(.SD, -isStart, rw)[, .(time[i], time[-i])]]
  ][Min >= end | Min < start, c("Min", "Max") := NA_real_]
}

fEACHI <- function(dtA, dtB) {
  dtA[
    , c("Min","Max") := dtB[
      dtA,
      on = .(id, time >= start, time < end), 
      .(Min=min(x.time), Max=max(x.time)),
      by=.EACHI][, c("Min","Max")]
  ]
}
```

Benchmarking a much larger dataset:

```
dtA <- data.table(id = rep(c("A", "B"), 2e5), start = sort(runif(4e5, 0, 2e5)), end = sort(runif(4e5, 0, 2e5)))
dtA[start > end, c("end", "start") := .(start, end)]
dtB <- data.table(id = rep(c("A", "B"), 1e6), time = sort(runif(2e6, 0, 2e5)))
setorder(dtA, id, start)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort = fsort(dta, dtB),
  .EACHI = fEACHI(dta, dtB),
  setup = dta <- copy(dtA),
  check = "equal",
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>    sort  258.6646  270.124  295.0626  304.3474  308.0906  322.8272    10
#>  .EACHI 2065.2458 2094.445 2115.2688 2104.5641 2152.5112 2157.1872    10
```

`fEACHI` gets increasingly slow as the interval widths increase, while `fsort` scales very nicely. For the example dataset below, `fsort` still takes a fraction of a second, while `fEACHI` explodes to 400 seconds.

```
dtA <- data.table(id = rep(c("A", "B"), 2e5), start = runif(4e5, 0, 2e5), end = runif(4e5, 0, 2e5))
dtA[start > end, c("end", "start") := .(start, end)]
dtB <- data.table(id = rep(c("A", "B"), 1e6), time = sort(runif(2e6, 0, 2e5)))
setorder(dtA, id, start)

system.time(dt1 <- fsort(copy(dtA), dtB))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.38    0.08    0.26
system.time(dt2 <- fEACHI(copy(dtA), dtB))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  520.44   23.03  399.72
identical(dt1, dt2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: As I dive into this, I think the caveat of non-overlapping ranges might need to be **bolded** for future readers

Comment: This is a really interesting approach @jblood94, thank you for providing it! It's definitely a different way to approach a large-ish problem. Unfortunately for me, the sample data I provided does suggest non-overlapping per ID, but that is not guaranteed in the real data, there are indeed overlapping regions of time. I tried for a bit to digest your code and adapt to this problem, but I think it's unlikely to work given how I _think_ you are doing it. Thank you again for the contribution! Clearly a case of over-simplifying sample data (on my part).

Comment: It's still quite doable without the assumption, just simpler with. I'll maybe take another crack at it tomorrow.

Comment: @r2evans, see the updated answer. Removing the assumption wasn't too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I think it's not possible to resolve this without doing a full expansion *somewhere*, so the next wicket would be runtime. With this 6-row sample, thelatemail's response was faster, but as the data scales to larger datasets the use of `collapse` gains parity, and at my current data it takes half the time (which is still on the order of *seconds*).

Also, I've changed the code below to use `first`/`last` instead of `min`/`max`, another aspect of the data I'm using (analogous in almost every way as far as performance and data-management goes).

thelatemail's:

```r
dtA[,
    c("min","max") := dtB[
      dtA,
      on=.(id, time >= start, time < end),
      .(min=first(x.time), max=last(x.time)),
      by=.EACHI][, c("min","max")]
    ]
```

equivalent in `collapse::`:

```r
joined <- dtB[, tm := time][dtA, on = .(id, tm >= start, tm < end)]
setnames(joined, c("tm", "tm.1"), c("start", "end"))
g <- collapse::GRP(joined, c("id", "start", "end"))
dtA[
  cbind(collapse::ffirst(joined[,.(time)], g = g),
        collapse::flast(joined[,.(time)], g = g),
        g$groups),
  on = c("id", "start", "end")]
```

AndreWildberg's recommend for a pure `dplyr` (>= 1.1.0) version is also notable, though I can't benchmark it at the moment (I'm still working with < 1.1.0).